# Ubuntu 11.04 update error

Tags: 11.04, gnome, drivers, xorg, ati

I just updated my Ubuntu 11.04, but now when starting it a black screen is shown and prints:

Checking battery state

Stopping system v runlevel compatibility

I tried to install the latest proprietary ATI driver but the error remains

Comment: I have the same problem on one of my ubuntu installs. (also ati drivers) I'll keep watch on this and let you know if I fix it. But I am thinking about just moving to archlinux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to start in recovery mode.  Select recovery mode, press e and add `nomodeset` to the line where you will probably find `quit splash`. Once your system is started, remove your latest ati-driver installation.